# Update if the id is matching on from the same table

Tags: postgresql

I have a table as below,

```
s_id s_score name category subcategory
123   10     core  account  subscription
123   10     core   values    numeric
456    9     esr    public    movies
789    6     john   service   others
789   6      john   digital   others
```

in which I am looking to update the the s_score column if my id is same. I need only one score, updating the other to null. Expected output as below.

```
s_id s_score name category subcategory
123   10     core  account  subscription
123          core   values    numeric
456    9     esr    public    movies
789    6     john   service   others
789         john   digital   others
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you know which row you want to update and which one you want to nullify?

Comment: It looks like your model may be wrong. You'd be better off modeling this as two tables: one for the score (`s_id`, `s_score`, `name`) and one for the category (`s_id`, `category`, `subcategory`) so that you can store only a single score.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
Yeah actually score and categories are from different tables when i do join i got 2 values as my s_id got 2 categories for the same s_id..

so if my s_id is repeating then i have to take only one s_score and keep others as null.

Comment: So you're actually looking to select the score only once for each name, you don't want to update any values in the database? Can you post the query that you're using to get the recordset currently?

Comment: select is also fine i need it along with both category and subcategory as well

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you have a single score for each s_id, but when you join it with the categories table you don't want to see the score for the second and third categories etc., so the problem lies in the query you're using to get the data, not the way that it's stored.

Comment: Yeah i need to see only one score..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing something conditionally based on the output of a `ROW_NUMBER` function may help you. Making several assumptions about your data model based on your comments, the following should be close to what you're looking for:

```
SELECT s.s_id, 
case when row_number()
    over (partition by s_id order by c.category) = 1 then s_score else null end as s_score,
s.name, c.category, c.subcategory
from s_scores s 
join categories c on s.s_id = c.s_id
```

For each s_id it's giving you a row number for the categories in that s_id. Where the row_number is 1 (i.e. it's the first category record for the s_id) it'll return the score. For other row numbers it'll return null.

This is ordering by category, which appears to be wrong according your expected results, hence my question about which row should have the score and which should be null. If you know that, just update the field referenced in the `order by`

Comment: Thanks for your replay.it really helped me.

Answer (score -1):

you can use update query as below;

```
update tableName set s_core='32' where s_id='123'
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay.. this will not help me.